# Refactor the [project]

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

[project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/project) is a meta tag. Its excerpt says:

> In software development, a project is a collection of files and resources used in the development of an application or service.

It attracts a lot of off-topic questions like these:

- [Taking over a project - What should I ask the previous programmer?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/436212/2982225)
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/30274520/2982225
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/30082870/2982225
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/30337269/2982225

Should it be burninated?

Comment: Yes, but there's a lot to go through.  We need to have a filter query that pulls out the questions that should be tagged ms-project.

Comment: Your last point is the same as the 2nd. The first 2 points belong on Programmers SE.

Comment: @user1803551 Thanks, corrected.

Comment: (Removed my previous comment).  We do have [[projects-and-solutions]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/projects-and-solutions), so all on topic questions about that topic should probably be merge into that tag.

Comment: We may also need to cleanup [multi-project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multi-project), [projects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/projects), [project-template](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/project-template), and [subproject](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/subproject)

Comment: Also perhaps [project-files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/project-files), [project-structuring](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/project-structuring), [multiple-projects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multiple-projects), [project-folder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/project-folder), and [project-structure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/project-structure),

Answer (score 7):

I would agree it's probably a bad tag that needs cleanup, but questions about VS projects aren't bad as such: project *files* in IDEs have their own structure and there are some unique considerations, so it's possible to ask useful questions about that side of tooling.

Burnination is therefore not really in order; what's needed is cleanup of the questions that *are* off-topic, wiki excerpt improvement to emphasize "no we really don't mean 'the project your boss assigned you'", and perhaps renaming the tag to something less error-prone.

Comment: [who read tag excerpts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/256114/213575)